# Cleaning Up Currency Data with Pandas Error

Tags: python, pandas

I want to clean up a column named net_con in my CandidateDT dataset from object to float. I keep getting an error message. Below is my code and my error message.

Code:

```
CandidateDT['net_con'] = CandidateDT['net_con'].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)
```

Error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(933.00)'

Comment: Well as you can see, negative numbers are written between parenthesis, you might want to remove them as well.

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Have you tried anything, done any research? What do/don't you understand from that error message? Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is just adding the parenthesis values to the `replace`. In this particular case, I'm replacing `(` with a `-` sign because `()` are used to show negative numbers. So it's only logical to to that replacement.:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4],'net_con':['1,000.00','(900.00)','(1,000,000.20)','300.00']})

data1['net_con'] = data1['net_con'].replace({'\$': '', ',': '', '\(': '-', '\)': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
   Id    net_con
0   1     1000.0
1   2     -900.0
2   3 -1000000.2
3   4      300.0
```